# S3 Bucket Lifecycle Configuration with Boto3 Lambda Function and getting MalformedXML format error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I created lambda function. In the function, I scanned all the s3 buckets if the bucket name contains "log" word. Took those buckets and apply the lifecycle. If the retention older than 30 days delete all kind of files under the buckets that contains "log" word. But when I triggered the code I get this format error.I couldn't fix it. Is my code or format wrong ?

**This is my python code:**

```
import logging
import boto3
import datetime, os, json, boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    response = s3.list_buckets()
    
    # Output the bucket names
    print('Existing buckets:')
    for bucket in response['Buckets']:
        #print(f'  {bucket["Name"]}')
        if 'log' in bucket['Name']:
            BUCKET = bucket["Name"]
            print (BUCKET)
            try:
                policy_status = s3.put_bucket_lifecycle_configuration(
                          Bucket = BUCKET ,
                          LifecycleConfiguration={'Rules': [{'Expiration':{'Days': 30,'ExpiredObjectDeleteMarker': True},'Status': 'Enabled',} ]})
            except ClientError as e:
                 print("Unable to apply bucket policy. \nReason:{0}".format(e))
```

**The error**

```
Existing buckets:
sample-log-case
sample-bucket-log-v1
template-log-v3-mv
Unable to apply bucket policy. 
Reason:An error occurred (MalformedXML) when calling the PutBucketLifecycleConfiguration operation: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema
```

I took below example from boto3 site, I just changed parameters didnt touch the format but I also get the format issue for this too :

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3')

response = client.put_bucket_lifecycle_configuration(
    Bucket='bucket-sample',
    LifecycleConfiguration={
        'Rules': [
            {
                'Expiration': {
                    'Days': 3650,
                },
                'Status': 'Enabled'
            },
        ],
    },
)

print(response)
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58244872/10692493) help?

Comment: According to the docs, `AccountId='string'` is required for `put_bucket_lifecycle_configuration`. I don't see it in yor code.

Comment: Before this port I tried that one and didn't work @jellycsc

Comment: @Marcin I didn't see any requirement like this in the documentation. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#bucketlifecycleconfiguration

Comment: @hammer89 You are right. Must have looked at other function by mistake. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_bucket_lifecycle_configuration), the 'Filter' rule is required if the `LifecycleRule` does not contain a 'Prefix' element (the 'Prefix' element is no longer used). 'Filter', in turn, requires exactly one of 'Prefix', 'Tag' or 'And'.

Adding the following to your 'Rules' in `LifecycleConfiguration` will solve the problem:

```
'Filter': {'Prefix': ''}
```

Comment: This fixed it for me

Comment: hi, newbie here. what whill happen if i dont input any prefix and let the value of 'Filter': {'Prefix': ''} to empty string <''> ? will the rule apply to all objects under the target bucket?